# Change slug of wishlist page

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to change the URL slug of my store `wishlist` page to `saved-items`.

> https://themeforest.net/item/cendo-responsive-magento-furniture-theme/12256163

I had successfully changed the contents into wishlist page. But having trouble while changing the URL slug from `wishlist` to `saved-items`. I am using magento "Version 2.1.0.1".

I am using `Cendo Magento Theme`. Can anyone tell me that how i can change it?

Comment: Jai can you help me with this.?

Comment: Thanx for your reply. Actually, I was changed it's contents from language file under this path `/catalog/language/english/account/wishlist.php`. But i am not able to find the slug of wishlist there.

Comment: @Jai Can you please help me where is the path of wishlist page slug.?

Comment: @jai Brother why you have deleted your comment. Lolz. :-D

Comment: Incorrect comment is deleted. I will check it and update with solution soon.